# Better place for home mount

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

Ok, i'm building large home server (Debian). Will I be able to mount **home partition** on **another disk** rather than another partition on the same one during the installation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle yes. You should be able to use any partition on any disk during the install process.

The Linux Mint Debian installer which is based on the Debian Installer does not have this option for some reason (see discussion [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=201&t=83144&hilit=%20installer)). Maybe this problem is also present in the debian installer (I've never used it) but I very much doubt it. *Every* other installer I've ever used allows you to spread a system over as many disks as you desire.

In the worst case scenario, if you only have access to one physical drive during the installation process, you could just set your /home there, and move it to the other partition after the installation process finishes.

Once you login to your new Debian system, mount the 2nd disk somewhere and copy your $HOME directory to this location. You then delete your actual $HOME directory and edit /etc/fstab to set the other drive to be mounted at /home (let me know if you need help with that). Then logout and log back in and everything should be properly set up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the installer presents you with this option when defining the folders for this disk. I've done this before for server installs.

Comment: Thanks! And how You define such idea to hold /home on another physical drive?

Comment: @user149770 I define it as a very good one :). It is the recommended approach, that way you can keep your $HOME if you switch distros, reinstall or whatever. You can also keep the same $HOME for multiple, different distributions.

Comment: @terdon yeah, i see advantages. In most cases we just define partition, not another disk. If the whole disk fails with /home partition on it - I think it's not what You've waiting for...

Comment: @user149770 True, but if you have $HOME on a separate disk, you don't lose your personal data if / fails. I think it is always a good idea to have separate disks if possible. That way if one fails you don't lose everything. It just, usually, isn't possible.

Comment: Using the same $HOME for different distros can break all kinds of things, also. Just be wary with it.

Comment: @Rob, yes, got it. But it will be one distro. Need just use separate physical drive for /home